# render json array in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1

My code in controller looks like this:

```
def dashboard
    @proj_users.each do |us|
      @users<<User.find(us.user_id).email
    end
    render :json=>@users
end
```

In my view page the javascript looks like this:

```
$(".clicked").click(function () {
  $.get("/dashboard", {
      clicked_id:this.id,
      user:$("#user").val()
    },
    function (data) {
      $("#all_users").hide();
      $("#proj_users").html(data);
    });
});
```

`@users` is an array containing email id. as you can see the `data` will have `@users`.

`@users` will be something like this 
`tm@gmail.com,tm2@gmail.com`

`$("#proj_users").html(data);` is not getting updated with data..

Kindly help me..

Comment: I changed render:json to render :text, now the div gets updated with the data.But data is displayed as "tm@gmail.com,tm1@gmail.com".I want it to display line by line..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
two ways
```

1) solution 1

```
  @proj_users.each do |us|
     email  = User.find(us.user_id).email + "<br>"
     @users << email
   end
   render :text=>@users
```

2) solution 2

```
  @proj_users.each do |us|
     @users<<User.find(us.user_id).email
   end
   render :json=>@users

   in view

   $(".clicked").click(function(){
        $.get("/dashboard",{
        clicked_id:this.id,
        user:$("#user").val()
        },
        function(data)
        {
         $("#all_users").hide();
         $.each(data, function(email){
           $("#proj_users").append(email + "<br>");
         }
        });
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the iteration:

```
def dashboard
  render :json => @proj_users.map(&:email)
end
```

Now you need to iterate (using .each() method) on the front end and put this in your html as shown by @ubaid's callback function.